How to add new tabs to devextreme TabPanel without re-rendering other tabs?
I created a testing component in react for testing tabs re-rendering in the devextreme tabPanel.
In the testing component, a random number is added first, and if a tab is added or removed, this number must not be changed, but in actual testing, the random number in the testing component is changed.
How can I disable re-render tabs when adding or removing tabs?
this is my sample code:
app component
    const tabPanelItems: tabPanelItem[] = [{
                title: "test",
                render: <Test/>,
                icon1: "remove",
                id: 2,
                selected: false
            },]
    
    const App = () => {
        const [tabItems, setTabItems] = useState<tabPanelItem[]>(tabPanelItems);
    
        const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(tabItems[1]);

    const onSelectionChanged = useCallback((args: any) => {
        setSelectedItem(args.selectedItem || args.addedItems[0]);
    }, [setSelectedItem]);


    const itemTitleRender = (item: tabPanelItem) => <>
        <span className="eki-icons tab-close" onClick={() => tabClose(item)}>close</span>
        <span>  {item.title} </span>
    </>;

        function tabClose(closeItem: tabPanelItem) {
            const newEmployees = [...tabItems];
            const index = newEmployees.indexOf(closeItem);
    
            newEmployees.splice(index, 1);
            setTabItems(newEmployees);
        }
     function AddClick() {
            setTabItems([...tabItems, {
                title: "base info",
                render: <BaseInfoApp/>,
                icon1: "user",
                id: 1,
                selected:false
            }]);
        }
    return <>
       <TabPanel dataSource={tabItems}
                                  ref={tabPanelRef}
                                  onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
                                  itemTitleRender={itemTitleRender}
                                  selectedIndex={tabItems.findIndex(tab => tab.selected)}
                                  showNavButtons={true}
                                  deferRendering={true}
                                  repaintChangesOnly={true}
                                  itemComponent={ShowTab}
                            // itemTemplate={ShowTab}
                        >
                        </TabPanel>
    </>

test Component:
    import React from "react";
    
     const Test = () => {
        var s = Math.random();
        return <><b>Random Number: {s}</b></>
    }
    export default React.memo(Test)

